# How to obtain crash logs from users running iOS 9

Tags: ios, ios9, crash-log

While we used to be able to obtain crash logs when [users sync'd with iTunes Connect](https://help.getpocket.com/customer/portal/articles/500338-how-to-find-the-iphone-ipad-app-crash-logs) at `~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/`, now most users don't do this. Thus, the new process for obtaining crash logs on iOS9 is [outlined here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1747/_index.html) by Apple.

Specifically:

1. Open Settings app
2. Go to Privacy, then Diagnostics & Usage
3. Select Diagnostics & Usage Data
4. Locate the log for the crashed app. The logs will be named in the format:
5. Select the desired log. Then, using the text selection UI select the entire text of the log. Once the text is selected, tap Copy
6. Paste the copied text to Mail and send to an email address as desired

However, this is what most my users end up sending to me, below. I see  nothing useful pertaining to a stack:

```
{"bug_type":"179","os_version":"iPhone OS 9.2 (13C75)"}
{
"scheduled" : true,
"machine_config" : "iPhone7,1",
"log_version" : 2,
"region_format" : "US",
"os_version" : "iPhone OS 9.2 (13C75)",
"language" : "en-US",
"sessions_data" : [
{
"app_arch" : "arm-64bit",
"app_build_version" : "0018",
"app_version" : "5.0001",
"app_adamid" : 00000000,
"app_sessionreporter_key" : "FFFFFFFF-1C4B-40E5-B631-BF9AE48B775D",
"app_storefront" : 143441,
"app_bundleid" : "com.myapp",
"app_events" : [
{
"date" : "2015-12-29T07:21:17-0800",
"state" : "foregroundRunning",
"type" : "app_session",
"duration" : 390
},
{
"date" : "2015-12-29T07:28:46-0800",
"state" : "foregroundRunning",
"type" : "app_session",
"duration" : 2
},
{
"date" : "2015-12-29T07:52:30-0800",
"state" : "foregroundRunning",
"type" : "app_session",
"duration" : 8
},
{
"date" : "2015-12-29T09:11:23-0800",
"state" : "foregroundRunning",
"type" : "app_session",
"duration" : 29
},
{
"date" : "2015-12-29T09:45:41-0800",
"state" : "foregroundRunning",
"type" : "app_session",
"duration" : 830
},
{
"date" : "2015-12-29T10:13:13-0800",
"state" : "foregroundRunning",
"type" : "app_session",
"duration" : 227
},
{
"date" : "2015-12-29T12:15:17-0800",
"state" : "foregroundRunning",
"type" : "app_session",
"duration" : 228
},
{
"date" : "2015-12-29T12:20:55-0800",
"state" : "foregroundRunning",
"type" : "app_session",
"duration" : 439
},
{
"date" : "2015-12-29T13:33:47-0800",
"state" : "foregroundRunning",
"type" : "app_session",
"duration" : 59
},
{
"date" : "2015-12-29T14:51:18-0800",
"state" : "foregroundRunning",
"type" : "app_session",
"duration" : 128
},
{
"date" : "2015-12-29T15:19:31-0800",
"state" : "foregroundRunning",
"type" : "app_session",
"duration" : 428
},
{
"date" : "2015-12-29T15:31:50-0800",
"state" : "foregroundRunning",
"type" : "app_session",
"duration" : 93
}
],
"app_is_beta" : false,
"slice_uuid" : "98293BB1-C91D-386F-825E-771AB68D9BE4",
"app_cohort" : "3|date=1310628600000&sf=143441"
},
{
"app_arch" : "arm-64bit",
"app_build_version" : "18972819",
"app_version" : "46.0",
"app_adamid" : 284882215,
"app_sessionreporter_key" : "B5155ABF-327F-4CCE-AEFB-8C733DC6EC96",
"app_storefront" : 143441,
"app_bundleid" : "com.facebook.Facebook",
"app_events" : [
{
"date" : "2015-12-29T10:00:55-0800",
"state" : "foregroundRunning",
"type" : "app_session",
"duration" : 473
}
],
"app_is_beta" : false,
"slice_uuid" : "F5D785A1-9DAF-32F7-A6DB-9738AF007735",
"app_cohort" : "3|date=1254358800000&sf=143441"
},
{
"app_arch" : "arm-64bit",
"app_build_version" : "20150927.114236",
"app_version" : "7.1.1",
"app_adamid" : 329670577,
"app_sessionreporter_key" : "D69640D5-7389-4148-B3DF-2093F1C486A4",
"app_storefront" : 143441,
"app_bundleid" : "com.taptaptap.CameraPlus",
"app_events" : [
{
"date" : "2015-12-29T15:04:40-0800",
"state" : "foregroundRunning",
"type" : "app_session",
"duration" : 685
}
],
"app_is_beta" : false,
"slice_uuid" : "327F314B-C34D-3015-A41C-0DB1374A0095",
"app_cohort" : "3|date=1301902200000&sf=143441"
}
],
"log_timestamp" : "2015-12-29T15:48:31-0800"
```

Does the process described on Apple's website above actually work? If so, any speculation on why all my users are able to provide is the truncated form below? And if not, what is the process by which I may obtain on-device crash logs from my users that does not involve trying to get them to install XCode?

Comment: Isn't it the crash report visible in Xcode > Devices Window? See this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html

Comment: The issue is that my users are not sophisticated and do not have, or cannot be expected to obtain/learn, XCode.

Comment: use crashlytics, its better

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever try [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/) yet? It send crash log automatically and report call stack for you and other useful details.

1) Install library using your Podfile

```
# Crashlytics
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
```

2) Import in AppDelegate

Objective C

```
#import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>
```

Swift

```
import Fabric
import Crashlytics
```

3) Initial crashlytics in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Objective C

```
[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];
```

Swift

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
```

Comment: I have -- however, Crashlytics has thousands of logs. I do not know which log applies to my customer with Crashlytics.

Comment: Then @esilver should specified user information (id, username) for crashlytics so you can identified your user and then you can search them.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac Users:

1. Open Finder (found in the Dock)
2. Click on the 'Go' menu at the top of your screen, and select 'Go to Folder'
3. Type (or paste): ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/
4. Open the folder with the same 'name' as your device. (Note: your device name appears in iTunes on the left side, under 'Devices').
5. Select Relevant Logs

**Courtesy link**: https://help.getpocket.com/customer/portal/articles/500338-how-to-find-the-iphone-ipad-app-crash-logs

Comment: Yes -- I linked to that very article in my original post. Unfortunately, most users today are not using iTunes to sync so these logs no longer exist on the actual device. My user is copy-pasting via the actual phone it appears, but is not getting actual helpful stack information.