# iOS app being rejected purportedly because of IPv6 connectivity

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm trying to submit and iPad app to the app store but it has been rejected twice. The reviewers state that the app is crashing after launch, which may be due to IPv6 connectivity or due to a watchdog timer, where the latter may be terminating the app because excessively long launch time. Below is the message I've received from the reviewers, which is a generic response that I've seen in related Stack Overflow posts:

> During review, your app failed to launch on iPad running iOS 10.2.1 on
>    Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.
>
> Specifically, when we selected the app on the Home screen, the app
>    displayed a launch image then quit unexpectedly. This may be because
>    iOS 10 uses a watchdog timer for apps; if an app takes too long to 
>    complete its initial startup, the operating system terminates the app.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please run your app on a device while connected to an IPv6 network
>    (all apps must support IPv6) to identify the launch issue, then revise
>    and resubmit your app for review. ...

I've set up a simulated IPv6 network based on Apple's Instructions here

https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html

and the app runs fine without crashing. Moreover the startup time is very fast - I have a very small image on the launch screen, 8kb - so there shouldn't be any memory issues. I don't know why its hanging up and crashing on their end.

Also, there are no networking interactions in the startup code - only in the root view controller. The latter was apparently never even called, as they state is crashing on the launch screen.

Does anyone have any experiences related to this and know how to overcome this?

Comment: Did they give you a crash log?  It probably doesn't have anything to do with ipv6, they just test on ipv6 networks and always mention it if an app crashes during review.

Comment: It says the problem was on an iPad. Did you try to actually re-create this on an iPad as opposed to an iPhone?

Comment: check the first answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522808/how-to-obtain-crash-logs-from-users-running-ios-9

Comment: @Mahmoud Fayez as the Op cannot reproduce the crash on their device, what use is this link?

Comment: Yeah it's on an iPad, it's strictly an iPad app.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't crash on my end so I can't obtain a crash log. Perhaps I can get the reviewers to send one.

Comment: I have the same problem... the server I am querying has no IPv6 compatibility (no AAAA record). App connects fine in my NAT64 at home, call to server works. But Apple's setup obviously does not allow call to IPv4 networks. So far I made bug-report, had conversations with App-Review and Developer support. To no avail...

Comment: Yeah we finally got it accepted - had nothing to do with what I stated above and what you stated. We simply made a video of it working and re-submitted, which was then accepted. I think they have some kind of automation or a bot for checking the app, at least in the early stages. If so the message was some generic message it spits out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you test your app by launching it with the device in Airplane mode?

Another possibility is did you test the app on a device that was connected to a WiFi access point which has had it's ethernet cable unplugged.

Apple has been reported to not approve apps that crash or lock up, even in these weird use cases.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try those out. Judging by how fast the review process started from the time I submitted the app, I think Apple's review process has become automated. We received the same form response from the 'reviewer' on both submissions, and when I replied to the reviewer my question wasn't answered and I received a vague, generic message that didn't address my questions. I think Apple has some kind of AI enabled to handle the reviews, hence the quick turn around. My other apps in the App Store took  stayed a bout a week in the review queue before they were reviewed.